# How install an Emacs package from file

Tags: emacs

I have Emacs installed on an internal PC in the organization that is not open  to the Internet.

For the sake of that question I'd like to install the "auto-complete" package.

I have downloaded a tar file from MELPA and a zip file from GitHub and copied them to my organization PC.

Now how can I install the auto-complete package using either the tar or zip file?

By the way I see in MELPA that the auto-complete package depends on the 
pop-up 0.5.0 package.

Should I install that before?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See <kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd> `package-install-file`

And yes, you will need to manually install any dependencies first, if Emacs will not be able to fetch them on its own.